# Circular waveguide excitationfor TE11 coefficients

Tags: waveguide

As we can see below. The theory says that A,B coeffietionts are depending on excitation.
I have simulated a circular waveguide, How do i need to excite my waveguide so i will see the A and B coeffiencts of the field change?

[image]

Comment: A and B are proportional to the amplitude of the excitation, so vary it.

Comment: if you excite the mode with a midplane *radial* launcher then in the TE11, n=1 mode depending on the setup of your coordinate system either $\cos\phi$ or $\sin\phi$ but not the other will couple to it strongly and the other will have much smaller amplitude. In your simulation, you should probably add a backshort a quarter wavelength from the launcher or drive the waveguide symmetrically in both directions.

Comment: The length of the launcher will only effect the input VSWR on the coax line but not the mode picture. Just make sure that the radius of the waveguide allows only the TE11 mode to propagate and you measure the field distribution at least three or more wavelengths away from the launcher.